# Latex: Acomodar texto y figura en ese orden

Tags: latex

estoy tratando de acomodar texto e imágenes **forzosamente en el orden indicado**, sin embargo en los cambios de hojas si no cabe la imagen pero sí más texto Latex rellena ese espacio con el texto siguiente, eso hace que no siga el orden que quiero lograr. Sería de mucha ayuda que pudieran orientarme, ¡Gracias!

Revisé [esta documentación](https://manualdelatex.com/tutoriales/figuras), sin embargo, no pude lograr lo que quería

Aquí les muestro un ejemplo de cómo estoy acomodando las cosas

```
\begin{tabbing} 
    Obtenemos:
    \= $ equation$ \\
    \> $ equation$ \\
\end{tabbing}

\begin{figure}[!h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=0.5\textwidth]{img.png}
    \caption{Circuito equivalente de la figura~\ref{fig:circuit2-1}}
    \label{fig:circuit2-2}
\end{figure}
                
\begin{tabbing} 
    Partiendo de~\ref{fig:circuit2-2} tenemos:
    \= $ equation$ \\
    \> $ equation$ \\
\end{tabbing}

\begin{figure}[!h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=0.5\textwidth]{img2.png}
    \caption{Circuito equivalente de la figura~\ref{fig:circuit2-2}}
    \label{fig:circuit2-3}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como en la otra respuesta, recomiendo probar la opción `H` que [el paquete `float`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/float) le permite agregar al `figure` (que es un **flotante**).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabbing} 
    Obtenemos:
    \= $ equation$ \\
    \> $ equation$ \\
\end{tabbing}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{img.png}
    \caption{Circuito equivalente de la figura~\ref{fig:circuit2-1}}
    \label{fig:circuit2-2}
\end{figure}
                
\begin{tabbing} 
    Partiendo de~\ref{fig:circuit2-2} tenemos:
    \= $ equation$ \\
    \> $ equation$ \\
\end{tabbing}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{img2.png}
    \caption{Circuito equivalente de la figura~\ref{fig:circuit2-2}}
    \label{fig:circuit2-3}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Sin embargo, tenga cuidado porque las imágenes tienen su propia altura y no pueden exceder el tamaño del cuadro de texto de la página. Su código no incluye su header, por lo que no es posible reproducir la página exactamente. Tampoco conocemos el aspect-ratio de las dos imágenes.

Un consejo útil que me viene a la mente es este: como arriba, podría también intentar reemplazar

```
\includegraphics[height=0.5\textwidth]{}
```

con

```
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{}
```

Esto podría haber sido deseado pero, si no, este pequeño cambio en particular podría ayudar.

Lo siento pero solo hablo italiano y utilicé el traductor de Google. `:)`

Answer (score 0):

anduve investigando más y resulta que es bastante sencillo.

Se tiene que incluir el paquete float y forzar la posición de la imagen con la posición forzada en este caso H.
Así quedaría la declaración de la figura `\begin{figure}[H]`

Y de esta manera todo el código que sugerí

```
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabbing} 
    Obtenemos:
    \= $ equation$ \\
    \> $ equation$ \\
\end{tabbing}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=0.5\textwidth]{img.png}
    \caption{Circuito equivalente de la figura~\ref{fig:circuit2-1}}
    \label{fig:circuit2-2}
\end{figure}
                
\begin{tabbing} 
    Partiendo de~\ref{fig:circuit2-2} tenemos:
    \= $ equation$ \\
    \> $ equation$ \\
\end{tabbing}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=0.5\textwidth]{img2.png}
    \caption{Circuito equivalente de la figura~\ref{fig:circuit2-2}}
    \label{fig:circuit2-3}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Y quedaría algo así.

La verdad no sé si hay una forma de hacerlo sin incluir librerías, si supieran una se los agradecería igualmente ;)